# passing data from one component to another with react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

im working on a 2 components weather app project. since the 2 components use a different API but still use the same  location query, i want to pass the query from the component 1 to component 2 as the API query. how do i pass the the query since im switching between the components with react router v6 useNavigation in a button. here's the code

```
    const api = {
        key : "5753c1f304f16ccb493d187a7351c953", 
        base : "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
    }

    const [weather, setWeather] = useState ('')
    const [query, setQuery] = useState ('')

 const search = (e) =>{
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        axios.get(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&appid=${api.key}`).then 
        ((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setWeather(response.data)
            setQuery('')
        } )
    }}

const navigate = useNavigate();

return (
    <>
      <div className='App'>
        <div className='search'>
          <input
          type='text'
          className='search-bar'
          value={query}
          onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          placeholder='Search Location...'
          onKeyPress={search} />
          <img className='button-icon' src={button} onClick={search}/>
        </div>
            <button className='viewStats' onClick={()=>navigate('/forecast')}>VIEW Forecast</button>

 </>
    
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release of React Router 6 brought huge changes to api.

You can pass the state from Component 1 to Component 2 like:

Pass your state from **Component 1** as follow:

```js
navigate('/your-route', { state : { query : ' your-query ' }})
```

You can recieve state in **Component 2** as follow:

```js
const { state } = useLocation();
const { query } = state;
```

**Above solution works for only React Router v6.**